# Birfucation Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following ODE: $$\dot x=y+ax(x^2+y^2), \dot y=-x+ay(x^2+y^2)$$
I used polar coordinates and I got $$\dot r=ar^3,\dot \theta=-1$$.

I have the equilibrium point (0,0) and calculate the jacobian matrix
and i got eingevalue $λ_1=i$ and $λ_2=-i$.

But i can not understand how to find the birfucation points of this ODE.

Comment: Your polar coordinates are wrong, could be a typo.

Comment: @Moo Oh, it was so obvious and I was stuck on it. Thanks